# Find inverse of element in a binary field

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, inverse

The question states:

Let us consider the field $GF(2^4)$ with multiplication modulo $x^4+ x^3+1$

Find all y such that $1010(y + 0011) = 1111$, in other words find y that satisfies $(x^3+x)(y +x+1) = x^3+x^2+x+1$

I tried to find the inverse for element $1010$ to multiply both sides of the equation and continue from there, I tried by solving the equation:

$(x^3+x)(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) = 1$

But the solution I get is that $a=0,b=1,c=1,d=0$ which doesn't produce the inverse element.

What is the inverse element of $(1010)$ in this field and how can I arrive at that solution?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know $$x^4+x^3+1=0 .\tag1$$
It will be useful to know
$$
x^4 = x^3+1\tag2$$
$$
x^5 = x^4+x=(x^3+1)+x = x^3+x+1\tag3$$
$$
x^6 = x^5+x^2 = (x^3+x+1)+x^2 = x^3+x^2+x+1\tag4
$$
These will be useful for doing a calculation like
$(x^3+x)(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) = 1$ that the OP proposes.

Compute
\begin{align}
1 &= (x^3+x)(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) 
\\
&=(a)x^6+(b)x^5+(c+a)x^4+(d+b)x^3+(c)x^2+(d)x+0
\\
&=(a+b+d+c+a+b)x^3+(a+c)x^2+(a+b+d)x+(a+b+c+a)
\\
&=(d+c)x^3+(a+c)x^2+(a+b+d)x+(b+c)
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
d+c&=0\\a+c&=0\\a+b+d&=0\\b+c&=1
\end{align}
So $d=c$, then $a=c$, then $b=a+d=c+c=0$, then $c=d=a=1$.  So
$$
(x^3+x)^{-1} = x^3+x+1
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just a detail, I'm trying to find the inverse of 1010 or $x^3 + x$ not $x^3 + x^2$

Comment: Fixed, I hope..

Comment: Thank you very much! I had an error on my calculations and your breakdown helped me greatly :D

Answer (score 2):

Here are some methods to compute this using a computer. The software is sagemath.

First, if the program supports defining finite fields with a given polynomial, you can just use that:

```
K.<a> = GF(2^4, modulus=x^4 + x^3 + 1)
(a^3 + a)^-1
  => a^3 + a + 1
```

You can also use the extended GCD which gives polynomials $u, v$ such that $uf + vg = 1$ so, modulo $f$, that gives $v = g^{-1}$.

```
K = GF(2)[x]
xgcd(K(x^4 + x^3 + 1), K(x^3 + x)) # K(...) means "as an element of K"
  => (1, x^2 + x + 1, x^3 + x + 1)
```

So $(x^3 + x + 1)(x^4 + x^3 + 1) + (x^3 + x + 1)(x^3 + x) = 1$.

You can also do it "by hand" using [companion matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). If $x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ is the minimal polynomial of your generator $\alpha$, then form the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & -d \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -c \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -b \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -a
\end{pmatrix}$$

In this way, $A$ also has that minimal polynomial. More specifically, each column represents $\alpha \cdot t$ for $t \in \{1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3\}$. Now you can compute $(A^3 + A)^{-1}$, and again the columns represent $(\alpha^3 + \alpha)^{-1} \cdot t$ for $t$ in that ordered basis. Of course, you want $t = 1$ to find $(\alpha^3 + \alpha)^{-1}$.

Here $(a,b,c,d) = (1,0,0,1)$ and

$$(A^3 + A)^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&0\\
1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&1\\
1&1&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Thus $(\alpha^3 + \alpha)^{-1} = 1 + \alpha + \alpha^3$ by reading the first column.

You can also just solve the linear system $(A^3 + A)u = (1,0,0,0)$ rather than the full inverse $(A^3 + A)U = I$. This works out to be the same linear system as given in GEdgar's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find the inverse of $x^3+x$ modulo $x^4+ x^3+1$ in $GF(2)[x]$

Given $a$ and $b$ you will find $u$ and $v$ such that
$$au+bv=\gcd(a,b)$$
in our example $\gcd(a,b)=1$ because $a$ is an irreducible polynomial and $\deg(a)>\deg(b)$. So we have
$$bv\equiv 1\pmod(a)$$
and $v$ is the multiplicative inverse.

We have to do some polynomial long divisions to find the greatest common divisor. From these divisions we can construct the representation of the greatest common divisor.

```
(x^4+ x^3+1) : (x^3+x) = x+1
 x^4     +^2
------------
x^3 + x^2 +1
x^3 + x
------------
x^2+x+1
```

so we have

$$ x^4+ x^3+1=(x^3+x) ( x+1)+ x^2+x+1$$
and further
$$x^2+x+1=(x^4+ x^3+1) + (x^3+x) ( x+1)$$
we continue this process and get

```
(x^3+x) : (x^2+x+1) = x + 1
 x^3+x^2+x
----------
x^2
x^2+x+1
-------
    x+1
```

$$ (x^3+x) = (x^2+x+1)(x+1) +(x+1) $$

$$x+1 = (x^3+x) + (x^2+x+1)(x+1)$$

```
x^2+x+1 : x+1 = x
x^2+x
-------
      1
```

$$x^2+x+1 =( x+1 )x +1$$
and so, by substituting the previous results
$$1= (x^2+x+1) +( x+1 )x \\
=  (x^2+x+1)+ ( (x^3+x) + (x^2+x+1)(x+1))x\\
=(x^2+x+1)(x^2+x+1)+(x^3+x)x\\
=((x^4+ x^3+1) + (x^3+x) ( x+1))(x^2+x+1)+(x^3+x)x\\
=(x^4+ x^3+1)(x^2+x+1) + (x^3+x)(( x+1))(x^2+x+1)+x)\\
=(x^4+ x^3+1)( x^2+x+1)+ (x^3+x)(x^3+x+1)$$

So
$$(x^3+x)(x^3+x+1)=1 \pmod{x^4+ x^3+1}$$

and the inverse of $1010$ in $GF(2^4)$ is $1011$.

---

Another way to calculate the inverse, at least for such small fields, to use the fact that

$$r\cdot r^{\text{ord} (r) -1}\equiv r^{\text{ord}( r)} \equiv 1$$
in a field. $\text{ord}(r)$ is a divisor of the order of the multiplicative group of the field. In our case this means
$$\text{ord}(x^3+x) \in \{3,5,15\}$$
and so
$$(x^3+x)^{-1} in \{(x^3+x)^2, (x^3+x)^4, (x^3+x)^{14}\}$$

So first we calculate $$(x^3+x)^2=x^6+x^2=x^3+x+1$$ and further
$$(x^3+x)^3=(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x)=1$$ and we have found the inverse $x^3+x+1$